# Join Other Table for Auth::User Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I have user and usergroup tables.

In user table, it contains: id, name, email, usergroup_id[fk]

In usergroup table, it contains: id[pk], usergroup

For name, I can get like this:

```
{{Auth::User()->name}}
```

How about for usergroup.usergroup?

Comment: Do you have a usergroup model?

Comment: You can simply create relation between the two tables to retrieve the data or vice versa use hasMany relationship

Comment: @hahahaha Try `{{Auth::user() -> usergroup() -> usergroup}}` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create relation `one to many` for  that.

**User.php**

```
public function userGroup(){
 $this->belongsTo('Usergroup');
}
```

**Usergroup.php**

```
public function users(){
 $this->hasMany('User');
}
```

Now you can get that by:

```
Auth::user()->userGroup->usergroup;
```

It might work :)

Answer (score 0):

User Model:

```
// here we saying that User belongs to a User group 
public function userGroup(){
     return $this->belongsTo(UserGroup::class,'usergroup_id');
}
```

UserGroup Model:

```
// here we saying that User group has many users 
public function user(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class,'usergroup_id','id');
}
```

From User Object you can do:

```
$userGroupObj = Auth::user()->userGroup();
// this would be a userGroup Object
// so now to get usergroup you can do
$userGroup = $userGroupObj->usergroup;

// Please make sure you check if($userGroupObj) before doing $userGroup = $userGroupObj->usergroup;

// So I would do something like
$userGroup = null;
$userGroupObj = Auth::user()->userGroup();
if($userGroupObj){
    $userGroup = $userGroupObj->usergroup;  
}
```

From UserGroupObject you can do:

```
$userObjCollection = $userGroupObject->user();
// this would be a user collection giving you all users in that group.
```

Comment: sorry, what is the User object means?

Comment: It's exactly like "Auth::User()" as you mentioned in question.
Auth::user() returns a user object and that would be current logged in user object.
But at times you can have situation where you want to find group of a user who may or may not be current logged in user.

So for generic user object I used user Object but in your case you can use Auth::user() and will get same result.

Comment: i tried to return 'Auth::user()->userGroup();' after login in the controller, but i got this error: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo could not be converted to string

Comment: That's allright let's see what it means. Auth::user()->userGroup() will return a object of type UserGroup. According to error message "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo could not be converted to string" it's saying that you trying to use it as string where as it is object.
So to test you can try dd(Auth::user()->userGroup()) it should print the group object. 
Now if you need usergroup of userGroup object you have to do something like 
$userGroupObj = Auth::user()->userGroup();
if($userGroupObj){
    $userGroup = $userGroupObj->usergroup;  // this is now string 
}